# Rest API request for Google Translation API

Tags: google-translate, google-translation-api

I have a problem with Rest API request for Google Translation API

My POST method is https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=MY_KEY

But I get an error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "API Key not found. Please pass a valid API key.",
        "errors": [
        {
            "message": "API Key not found. Please pass a valid API key.",
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "badRequest"
        }
        ],
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

Please help me to understand where the problem comes from.

Comment: Message clearly says that Key is not valid. Please add your valid key in place of My_KEY.

Comment: HI Sandy i add my key but the error is still the same

Answer (score 17):

You might want to try starting with [one of the samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/translate/cloud-client) as opposed to trying to build your own client library or get/POST with REST.  If you must use REST, the following example may be helpful:

```
https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=your-key-here&q=cheese&target=es
```

Replace the API key with the one that you have enabled access to the translate API on.

Comment: Thank you but the error is the same. I think the mistake comes from that I do not pay

Comment: Yes, you probably need to configure billing before the API will work.

Comment: What about v3?, How can we make a rest call