# Error Request to Google App script Translate API using Axios Vue js 3

Tags: google-apps-script, vuejs3

First time to use google app script translate api , trying to do a request using axios with vue js 3 but i got the following error↓↓↓
[image: Error Messege]

Bellow is my google app script api code
[image]

The api work properly, When I try to access it via url from address bar returning the translated word like bellow.

[https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbweJFfBqKUs5gGNnkV2xwTZtZPptI6ebEhcCU2_JvOmHwM2TCk/exec?text=こんにちわ&source=ja&target=en](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbweJFfBqKUs5gGNnkV2xwTZtZPptI6ebEhcCU2_JvOmHwM2TCk/exec?text=%E3%81%93%E3%82%93%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A1%E3%82%8F&source=ja&target=en)

Bellow is my component code,
The flow is when the keyup event triggered the translate method will be accesing the api using axios to get the result.

```
<template>
<div class="container grid">
    <div class="translate">
        <div class="form">
            <select name="formerLang" id="formerLang" v-model="formerLang">
                <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>_
                <option value="ja">Japanese</option>
                <option value="en">English</option>
                <option value="id">Indonesia</option>
            </select>
            <label>TO:</label>
            <select name="targetlang" id="targetLang" v-model="targetLang">
                <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>_
                <option value="jp">Japanese</option>
                <option value="en">English</option>
                <option value="id">Indonesia</option>
            </select>
            <textarea name="formerLangInput" id="formerLangInput" class="form-control"  v-model="text" @keyup="translate"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="result">
            <h3>Result</h3>
            <input type="text" name="result" id="result" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <h3>Descriptions</h3>
            <input type="text" name="description" id="description" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
export default {
    setup() { 
    },
    data(){
        return{
            formerLang:'',
            targetLang:'',
            text:'',
            result:'',
            description:''
        }
    },
    methods:{
           translate(){
               console.log(this.text);
               axios.get(`https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbweJFfBqKUs5gGNnkV2xwTZtZPptI6ebEhcCU2_JvOmHwM2TCk/exec?
               text=${this.text}&source=${this.formerLang}&target=${this.targetLang}`,
               {headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}}
               ).then(response => (console.log(response)))
           }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')

    },  
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rest API request for Google Translation API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149584/rest-api-request-for-google-translation-api)

Comment: it is GCP? mine using google app script so its litle bit different

Comment: "Google Apps Script" description: "Use for questions about Google Apps Script, Google's JavaScript-based cloud scripting platform" - isn't it just a wrapper to accept google cloud?

Comment: im not sure about it because im new here, im using Class Language App https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/language/language-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your current situation and your goal as follows.

- You have a Web Apps with `doGet` created by Google Apps Script.
- You want to access to your Web Apps using axios.

From your error message, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
axios.get(`https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbweJFfBqKUs5gGNnkV2xwTZtZPptI6ebEhcCU2_JvOmHwM2TCk/exec?
text=${this.text}&source=${this.formerLang}&target=${this.targetLang}`,
{headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}}
).then(response => (console.log(response)))
```

#### To:

```
axios.get(`https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbweJFfBqKUs5gGNnkV2xwTZtZPptI6ebEhcCU2_JvOmHwM2TCk/exec?
text=${this.text}&source=${this.formerLang}&target=${this.targetLang}`)
.then(response => (console.log(response)))
```

- I thought that in this case, `{headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}}` is not required to be used.

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I cannot find the settings of your Web Apps in your question. So when you modified like above and an error occurs, please check the settings. In this case, it supposes that your Web Apps is deployed as `Execute as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone`. Please be careful this.

  - When you changed this, please modify the deployment as new version. By this, it is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.
- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this at the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Thank you in advance, My web app deploy settings is the same as you written above but still get the same error. but this information is very usefull for helping me when using Google App Script in the future, Thanks for the information.

Comment: @shinichirou ikebe Thank you for replying. The specification of Web Apps was changed from March 15, 2021. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#march_15_2021) So in that case, as a test of this modification, how about the following flow? 1. Create a new Google Apps Script project and copy and paste your script. 2. Deploy Web Apps and test it using a simple request again. Because when I tested your Google Apps Script and above modified axios request, I confirmed that it worked. If this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: still got the following error "has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: @shinichirou ikebe Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. In my environment, no error occurs. I apologize for this situation. So, although I'm not sure about your current script, how about testing it using a simple script as follows?

Comment: @shinichirou ikebe GAS side is `const doGet = _ => ContentService.createTextOutput("Done.");`. And, Web Apps is deployed as `Execute as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone`. axios side is `axios.get(url).then((res) => console.log(res.data)).catch((err) => console.log(err));`.

Comment: @shinichirou ikebe I thought that at first, when the script and method without the error could be found using a simple script, when you add more script in the future, it will help to find the reason of the issue.

Comment: nothing change , maybe something wrong with my axios

Comment: @shinichirou ikebe Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, when I tested above sample script, no error occurs. Alt least, above modification and above samples can be worked. So I thought that your environment might be different from my one as you say. But, in the current stage, I cannot point out about the clear differences. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So, when I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of the reason.

Comment: Thank you for replying. no need to apologize its not your fault , its my problem cant resolve this error, i very appreciate your effort for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

TL:DR Google Translate API is a paid service. You can create a trail account with limits. "First 500,000 characters* per month" is free. So you need to sign up and get an API key to use this service.

Quoting [google.com/translate/docs/setup](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup):

> To start using Cloud Translation, you need a project that has the
> Cloud Translation API enabled and credentials to make authenticated
> calls. The following sections detail how to get set up before you make
> your first call to the Cloud Translation API.
>
> Cloud Translation is available in two editions. Before you begin,
> decide which edition you will use because their client library
> installations are different.

[editions#basic](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/editions#basic)

> Cloud Translation - Basic enables you to dynamically translate between
> languages using Google's general translation models. Basic is
> optimized for simplicity and scale. It's a good fit for applications
> with primarily casual user generated content, such as chat, social
> media, or comments. See **Pricing** and **Quotas and Limits** for details.

Emphasis mine.